# How to allow external link in angularjs when using ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ng-bind-html

Here is the rendered code

```
<div>dfdbfbdfbdfbdfbdfbfb gdfgfggtbrtb  
   <a href="www.github.com" target="_blank"> rtrtrt
   </a>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

I get this, when i click in the hyperlinked text

```
https://myapp.io/www.github.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use HTTP protocol with external links, if you don't use HTTP before the link, it will be considered as local resource link. In your above mentioned code you should use

```html
<a href="http://www.github.com">Github</a>
```

Instead of

```html
<a href="www.github.com">Github</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<a href="https://www.github.com" target="_blank">` the link destination you pasted is relative to the domain you are in.

Comment: i have tried to replace the href to ng-href.... and that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: the external link is opened from an angular app

so in this case i want to remove the main domain and redirect to the external link given

Comment: i tried the above hack, and i get 

`https://https//gdpr-info.eu/`

i am using this method to add the http
string.replace('="','="https://')

Comment: Make sure you are correctly adding `:` after https on your link

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use $window in the controller and a ng-click in the view.
In the view:

```
<a ng-click="myFunctionToGoAwayFromAngularJS()">click me</a>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.myFunctionToGoAwayFromAngularJS = function () { $window.open("https://www.github.com"); };
```

Obviously you need to inject $window in your controller. This way you can assign ng-click in whatever tag you want, not only to anchor tags.